# Execute raw SQL using ServiceStack.OrmLite

Tags: sql, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am working ServiceStack.OrmLite using MS SQL Server. I would like to execute raw SQL against database but original documentation contains description of how to do it with SELECT statement only. That is not enough for me.

I cant find the way to run anything as simple as that:

```
UPDATE table1
SET column1 = 'value1' 
WHERE column2 = value2
```

Using, for example:

```
var two = db.Update(@"UPDATE table1
    SET column1 = 'value1' 
    WHERE column2 = value2");
```

Running this expressions with  db.Update() or db.Update<> produces uncomprehensive errors like

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UPDATE'.

I would like to use raw sql because my real UPDATE expression uses JOIN.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`db.Update` is for updating a model or partial model as shown in [OrmLite's Documentation on Update](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/#update). You can choose to use the loose-typed API to build your update statement, e.g:

```
db.Update(table: "table1", 
  set: "column1 = {0}".Params("value1"), 
  where: "column2 = {0}".Params("value2"));
```

The `Params` extension method escapes your values for you.

Otherwise the way to execute any arbitrary raw sql is to use `db.ExecuteSql()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. db.ExecuteSql() is exactly what i needed to run UPDATE on joined table.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a SELECT statement and you want to execute using raw sql you can use:

```
List<Person> results = db.SqlList<Person>("SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Age < @age", new { age=50});
```

Reference: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#typed-sqlexpressions-with-custom-sql-apis